# unable to stop impersonation of an GCP Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, impersonation

Weeks ago I've started impersonation of an ServiceAccount using [gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) command. Now I can't get back to my normal user account and every command I run is using impersonation, even gcloud config set project ... throws:
`WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation.`

I tried gcloud auth login, gcloud init and more... Removed credentials.db file from .config/gcloud of my Linux home directory. The docs have nothing on a subject how to stop impersonation.

**Does anyone know the proper command to stop impersonation?**

Comment: If this is supposed to be a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), note it must still be a separate, high quality question ([ask]) and answer ([answer]).

Comment: If `gcloud init` did not work, I would consider that a bug.

Answer (score 0):

**This might not be production-ready solution or there are better options**, but it worked for me

1. First try `gcloud auth application-default login` and follow instructions (browser will open) - it might help

**If above didn't help for you, I did additional step before rerunning the command above:**

1. I've removed application default credentials from the config folder:
   `rm ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
2. run again: `gcloud auth application-default login`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove service account impersontation config part from `.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default`

> Might be different file in `configurations` if `.config/gcloud/active_config` is not set as
> `default`

2. Delete `.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`
3. Run `gcloud auth application-default login`